# Space gap in mobile view CSS

Tags: css

I'm currently having trouble styling the css for mobile. When you view the site on mobile you'll see there's a big gap between the header and nav. You can view the mobile simulator here http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php?u=http://www.angelbeats.nu Does anyone know how I can fix this? I want to remove that gap so the content div can move up

Comment: `#header` is having `height 270px` remove  that or add it in media query

Comment: if I remove the height then the desktop view won't see the header image anymore

Answer (score 0):

You must override your height in your media-query #header rule

```
media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
    #header {
        background-image: url(http://transmog.net/cgi-bin/nph-mobilewebonastick-scroll.cgi/000000A/http/www.angelbeats.nu/wp-content/themes/angelbeats/images/mobile-header.jpg);
        overflow-y: hidden ! important;
        overflow-x: hidden ! important;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;// add this rule
    }
```